# How do CAVV and XID look like?

Tags: validation, e-commerce, payment-gateway, 3d-secure

`CAVV` and `XID` are tokens to prove a 3D Secure transaction was authenticated. But how do they look like? If I receive one, how can I validate it really is a CAVV or XID? Can it be any 28-character long string? Or are there some rules (like the Luhn formula for credit card numbers)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**CAVV/AVV/UCAF/AEVV** values can be encoded according to the merchants configuration in either Base64 encoding or Hex encoding.

- A Base64 encoding merchant configuration will produce values of 28 or 32 characters.
- A Hex encoding merchant configuration will produce values of 40 or 48 characters.
- The value when decoded will either be 20 bytes for CAVV or 20 or 24 bytes if the value is AAV (MasterCard UCAF).

Similarly **XID** will be encoded according to the merchants configuration in either Base64 encoding or Hex encoding as well.

- A Base64 encoding merchant configuration will produce values of 28 characters.
- A Hex encoding merchant configuration will produce values of 40 characters.